# How to create case using Sforce connection

Tags: visualforce, javascript, case, javascript-remoting

**Javascript**

```
<apex:page standardController="case">
<script type="text/javascript"> 

     function insertcase() 
         { 
         alert('came');
         var con = sforce.connection.login("username", "password");        

         var cas = new sforce.SObject("Case");
         alert(cas);
         cas.description = document.getElementById("description").value;
         alert(cas.description);
         alert('inside');           

         var caseResult = sforce.connection.create([cas]);  
         alert(caseResult);
         alert('If Creation');

         alert(cas.description);




                   else {
                   var a = sforce.connection.create([cas]);
                   alert('Else creation');
                   var b = a[0].id;
                   alert(b);
                   }  

             }
</script>


  <apex:form >

<apex:inputfield value="{!Description}"/>
  <apex:commandButton value="click me" onclick="insertcase();"/>
   </apex:form>


    </apex:page>
```

Problem:
Case is not getting created.

I have to create a case using sforce without controller .

Please help me to solve this issue.

thanks in advance.

Comment: you can use Remote Objects : https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_remote_objects_using_create.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to add JS files for AJAX toolkit.. Add below script and session Id(If you are using inserting records in same org no need to use username password.)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
sforce.connection.sessionId = '{!$Api.Session_ID}'; 
</script>
<script src="/soap/ajax/35.0/connection.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/soap/ajax/35.0/apex.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

If you want to create any record then use like this..

In this example I am creating Account record

```
<apex:page>

    <script src="/soap/ajax/35.0/connection.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/soap/ajax/35.0/apex.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        sforce.connection.sessionId = '{!$Api.Session_ID}';
    </script>
    <script>
        function test() {
            var account = new sforce.SObject("Account");
            account.Name = "my new account";
            var result = sforce.connection.create([account]);

            if (result[0].getBoolean("success")) {
                log("new account created with id " + result[0].id);
            } else {
                log("failed to create account " + result[0]);
            }
        }
    </script>
    <input type="button" onclick="test()" value="Create Acc" />
</apex:page>
```

Comment: still its not working. I think the problem is with java script

Comment: @Sandra if you are trying to create record then check my updated ans Example. like wise try to create Case record with all the required fields

Comment: @Sandra also always check browser console.. If you are getting error in javascript or not..

Comment: `<script type="text/javascript">
sforce.connection.sessionId = '{!$Api.Session_ID}'; 
function test()
{
alert("hello");
var account = new sforce.SObject("Account");
account.Name = "my new account";
var result = sforce.connection.create([account]);

if (result[0].getBoolean("success")) {
  log("new account created with id " + result[0].id);
  alert("new account created with id " + result[0].id);
} else {
  log("failed to create account " + result[0]);
  alert("failed to create account " + result[0]);
}
}
</script>` <apex:commandButton value="click me" onclick="test();"/>

Comment: I tried with this. still not working

Comment: @Sandra check my updated ans. Have you tried like that ? Just now tested in my org It is creating Acc record

Comment: @ Ratan Thanks Its working, I will proceed  with this  further. I f any doubt will let u know..